# Angular reactive form filter list of checkboxes

Tags: angular, forms

I have a list of checkboxes and an input field.
The checkboxes each have a name.

I want to filter the list by name, using the value from the input field.
The expected result is that only those checkboxes are visible, which name contains the text typed in the input field.

This is super trivial in AngularJS, and it's also easy to do with Angular's template-driven forms.

But I need to do it in a reactive form. 
How on Earth do I do that?

**Example with code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-list-filter**

Comment: can you add your code in to stackblitz. and provide some detailed explanation

Comment: Sure! There's now a Stackblitz example.

Answer (score 1):

You can either make your list of checkboxes an Observable and change the value of the obsverable every time the user searches. or you can store two copies. the first would hold the master list of checkboxes, and the second would hold the filtered results based on the search term.

Made a few adjustments to get you started based on approach 2. [seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-list-filter-yuvckn)

- I adjusted the HTML to loop through the "filtered_data" variable.
- this variable gets updated in the form control value changes.  using
  a regexp "case insensitive' pattern to match against the name of each
  box
- I also added logic so all controls are reset when you clear out
  the input field.

hopefully that is enough to get you started.

If you need to make this an observable, reach out.

Comment: Best and clean!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Create one more name form control in form array. With that you will know that which box is checked or not by name.

[Angular Code with checkboxes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-list-filter-sqgg59?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-form%2Fmy-form.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question at all. I'm asking about how to filter the list.